# Какой тип возвращает функция в данном случае?

Tags: javascript, функции, return

В данном случае непонятно что  за тип возвращается в последней строке?
Что это, массив с функциями ?

```
function Calculator() {

    var methods = {
        "-": function(a, b) {
        return a - b;
    },
        "+": function(a, b) {
        return a + b;
    }
};

this.calculate = function(str) {

    var split = str.split(' '),
    a = +split[0],
    op = split[1],
    b = +split[2]

    if (!methods[op] || isNaN(a) || isNaN(b)) {
        return NaN;
    }

return methods[op](a, b);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Строка, переданная в `this.calculate` разбивается через пробелы, где `a` и `b` типкастятся в числа, а `op`, в свою очередь, содержит операцию (конкретно здесь может быть только сложение и вычитание - они заранее прописаны в локальном объекте `methods`)
Затем проверяется - существует ли указанная операция в объекте `methods` и не являются ли переданные числа `a` & `b` NaN. (если хоть что-нибудь из этого `true`, результатом выполнения становится NaN)

Если это не так, то вызывается необходимая функция по ключу из объекта `methods`, которая входными данными принимает два числа и возвращает результат выполнения. (сложение или вычитание конкретно в Вашем примере.)

UPD. как [подсказали](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/870468/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5/870469#comment1410288_870469) в комментариях, стоит уточнить - тип возвращаемого значения всегда `number`.

Comment: Отлично! Но, думаю, что забыли уточнить - тип возвращаемого значения: `number` (NaN [тоже](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.23) )

Comment: @UModeL, упс, да, этот момент упустил. Каюс, не бейте, правил ответ;)